# Should I use SqlGeometry or SqlGeography?

Tags: sql-server, geocoding, geospatial

We're in a bit of internal conflict on this issue, and can't seem to come to a happy conclusion.

We'll only be storing latitudes and longitudes, and possibly simple polygons.  All we need it for is computing distance between two points (and possibly to see if a point is within a polygon), and the entirety of the data is in such close proximity to make planar estimations acceptable.

Since our requirements are so relaxed, half of the dev team suggests using `SqlGeometry` types, which are apparently simpler.  I'm having trouble accepting this, though, since we're storing *geographic data*, which seems like storing them in `SqlGeography` is the right thing to do.  Also, I'm not finding any substantive evidence that the `SqlGeometry` data type is that much easier to work with than the `SqlGeography` type.

Does anyone have advice as to which type would be more appropriate for this relatively simple scenario?

Comment: Is there *any* possibility that your application could grow to the point that spherical data becomes a requirement?

Comment: Hmm... I haven't done enough with the spatial data in SQL Server to have an informed opinion. Code up the things that you've described both ways and see which one is easier. If it's a wash, I'd say the geography type is more appropriate. But you might uncover their trepidation in the spiking process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a question of comparing features, or accuracy, or simplicity - the two spatial datatypes are for working with different sorts of data.

As an analogy, suppose you were choosing the best datatype for a column that contained a unique identifier for each row. If that UID only contained integer values, you'd use *int*, whereas if it was a 6-character alphanumeric value you'd use *char(6)*. And if it had variable-length unicode values, you'd use *nvarchar* instead, right?

The same logic goes for spatial data - you choose the appropriate datatype based on the values that that column contains; if you're working with geographic (i.e. latitude/longitude) coordinates, use the *SqlGeography* datatype. It's that simple.

You *can* use SqlGeometry to store latitude/longitude values, but it would be like using *nvarchar(max)* to store an integer... and I promise you it will lead to further problems down the line (when all your area calculations come out measured in degrees squared, for example)

Comment: although I agree with you, the problem described by the OP seems really simple. He even mentions that the entirety of the data is in close proximity, so the distance calculation error should be negligible. Don't you ever make an exception regarding lat/lon -> geography? I'm asking this because I've had my share of problems with SqlGeography and ogr2ogr, NH Spatial, QGIS, Sharpmap, etc, and sometimes, especially when the spatial data is not the core of the solution but something accessory, going with SqlGeography just doesn't seem worth the trouble (IMHO).

Comment: @psousa, do you have any links to share with your specific problems concerning the SqlGeography type?

Comment: I don't have any links on the top of my head, but for example: ogr2ogr sometimes flipping the lat/lon fields when importing geography data (in one of the newer versions), QuantumGIS (the latest version) not opening SQL geography data, SharpMap not supporting SQL Geography data, NH Spatial requiring some special overrides to handle geography data, harder to create a polygon because you have to supply the correct ring orientation... Anyway, Alastair has a point, in theory it seems logical to use SqlGeography. Just measure the pros and cons.

Comment: You're correct, @psousa - the geography datatype *is* more picky than the geometry datatype, but that's because working with ellipsoidal coordinates is more complicated than working with flat coordinates, and your data needs to be of a higher quality. If your reason for using the geometry datatype is "because it's less trouble" (because it ignores ring orientation issues of your source data etc.) then you're just hiding the problem - the real solution is to fix your source data so that it *does* work with the geography datatype...

Answer (score 6):

The SqlGeography type has less methods available than SqlGeometry (especially in Sql 2008).

[SqlGeography reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx)

[SqlGeometry reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee642119%28v=sql.105%29)

For example, suppose you want to get the centroid of a polygon in Sql2008. You have a native method for that in geometry, but not in geography.

Also, it has the following limitations:

- You can't have a geography exceeding one hemisphere
- The ring-order matters when creating the polygon

Also, most API and libraries available (that I know of) handle geometries better than geographies.

That said, if the distance calculation has to be precise, you have large distances and have coordinates all over the world, geography would probably be a better fit. Otherwise, and according to your description of the problem, you would be well served with the geometry type.

Regarding your question: "is that much easier to work?". It depends. Anyway, and as a rule of thumb, for simple scenarios I typically opt for SqlGeometry.

Anyway, IMHO you shouldn't worry too much on that decision. It's relatively easy to create a new column with the other type and migrate the data if necessary.

Comment: thanks, @psousa, for this pragmatic argument.  I'm wondering, what does it take to convert the pure geometric result of a calculation into an appropriate unit of measure?  For example, calculating the distance between two `Point`s or calculating the area of a `Polygon`?

Comment: For instance, calculating the distance between points (1,2) and (2,2) would return `1` for Geometry, but would return `~111,252` for Geography (I'm using bogus coordinates for the sake of example).  It seems very nice that Sql Server gives you the distance in meter (or whatever you specify) instead of having to convert the pure geometric result into whatever it is you want.  Are there any other issues to be concerned with when doing calculations against geometric data that will then need to be converted?

Comment: Distance calculation, area calculation, intersection with large polygons (because of the earth curvature). Anyway, I see your doubts regarding geometry, and I've been in that exact spot for a specific project that I had. You can also go with geography without any problem. It necessary, converting from geography to geometry is very, very easy (although the opposite not quite).

Answer (score 2):

Four years later, it has become apparent that we should have stored the data in `SqlGeometry` instead of `SqlGeography`.

Why?

We were importing information from legislative district maps, and their data was stored in `SqlGeometry`.  When determining if a particular lat/long was within a certain legislative district boundary, we'd get inconsistent results when the point was close to two boundaries.

This required us to do additional work to identify locations that were "close" to a boundary, and manually verify that they were assigned to the proper district.  Not ideal.

**Moral of the story:** if you're relying on any data, consider what type it's stored in to help guide your decision.